# Who wants to be a millonaire pygame - 50:50 Joker

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to program "Who wants to be a millionaire" with pygame.
Now I'm kind of struggling with setting up the 50:50 joker.

I have setup the code shown below.
This draws 4 rectangles and inputs the texts from question.

```
import pygame

pygame.init ()
font = pygame.font.SysFont ('Arial', 22)
window = pygame.display.set_mode ((1680, 945))
pygame.display.set_caption ("Who will become a millionaire?")

def draw_button (x, y, answer, width, height, bgcolor):
    pygame.draw.rect (window, bgcolor, (x, y, width, height))
    text = font.render (answer, False, (0, 0, 0))
    window.blit (text, (x + 10, y + 10))

draw_button(100, 600, question["answers"][0], 450, 70, (0,0,255))
draw_button(650, 600, question["answers"][1], 450, 70, (0,0,255))
draw_button(100, 750, question["answers"][2], 450, 70, (0,0,255))
draw_button(650, 750, question["answers"][3], 450, 70, (0,0,255))
```

Now what I want to do is if the user chooses to use the 50:50 Joker by pressing `KP1`, I want to overwrite 2 of the 3 wrong answers with an empty rectangle.
What is the best way to randomly choose 2 out of the 3 and overwrite them?

```
def wait ():
    running = true
    while running:
        for ev in pygame.event.get ():

            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return len (monies)
            elif ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if ev.key == pygame.K_KP1: # 50: 50
                    draw_joker_chosen (150.50)

                    if current_question ["rightQ"] == 0:
                        fifty_fifty_a ()
                        delete_joker (150.50)

                    elif current_question ["rightQ"] == 1:
                        fifty_fifty_b ()
                        delete_joker (150.50)

                    elif current_question ["rightQ"] == 2:
                        fifty_fifty_c ()
                        delete_joker (150.50)

                    elif current_question ["rightQ"] == 3:
                        fifty_fifty_d ()
                        delete_joker (150.50)
```

I want the `fifty_fifty` function to randomly pick 2 wrong answers from a list of 3, and overwrite them, for example if answer `a` is the correct one, I want to call two of these 3 randomly.

```
b = pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,0,255), (650, 600, 450,70))
c = pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,0,255), (100, 750, 450,70))
d = pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,0,255), (650, 750, 450,70))
wrong = [b,c,d]
...
```

Can I somehow assign them variables and put them into a list, and then randomly pick 2 from the list and execute only them?

I tried some stuff, but didn't get it to work.

Comment: to choose 2 rom 3 - `remove = random.choices(["A","B","C"], k=2)`

Comment: if you want to choose 2 of 3 to overwrite them then you can choose one to keep it - `keep = random.choice(["A","B","C"])` (this function's name doesn't have char `s` at the end)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want. I think the following piece of code should give you some inspiration.

```
import random


def randomly_discard_two_wrong_answers(answers, correct_answer_index):
    false_answers = answers[:correct_answer_index] + answers[correct_answer_index + 1:]
    discarded_answers = random.sample(false_answers, 2)
    return [answer if answer not in discarded_answers else None for answer in answers]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    answers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    for i in range(10):
        new_answers = randomly_discard_two_wrong_answers(answers, 2)
        print(new_answers)
```

Result:

```
[None, None, 'C', 'D']
[None, 'B', 'C', None]
[None, None, 'C', 'D']
['A', None, 'C', None]
[None, None, 'C', 'D']
['A', None, 'C', None]
[None, 'B', 'C', None]
[None, None, 'C', 'D']
[None, None, 'C', 'D']
[None, None, 'C', 'D']
```